# PHPMailer show plain text email always in monospace font

Tags: php, email, fonts, phpmailer, plaintext

I'm trying to setup plain text email as an alternative for the HTML email content. To test, I sent emails with only the plain text (no HTML). The text email shows up fine in Gmail and Zoho Mail (that's a business email client). However, they are all using regular font like Arial.

The problem is, assuming that plain text emails would automatically use monospace font, I created a plain text "tabular" data using `str_pad` and `strlen` to automatically generate it. But in the end, both email clients made my efforts worthless by displaying the data in regular font, completely destroying the tabular structure.

Aside from user preference of the recipient choosing what font to use for plain text emails, is there any way to control how plain text emails are displayed? I want them to always be forced to display in monospace font in any mail client.

I thought `<pre>` tags before and after might work, but that's HTML and will probably just show as text `&lt;pre&gt;`. (PS: I was right.)

Bonus kudos for anyone who can give a neat alternative to showing tabular data in plain text.

Comment: What happens if you use \t instead of str_pad?

Comment: @l'L'l: That won't work reliably either -- if the amount of content in the columns varies by more than a tab's width, subsequent columns will be off by one (or more).

Comment: @I'L'I what duskwuff said.

Comment: FWIW, I'm concluding there is no way to hint or instruct email clients to use a `monospace` font. Since I don't have control over the font used by a client software, I reviewed the plain text email layout instead, so that it doesn't depend on a `monospace` font-based tabular structure. I did this by converting the table in the HTML version into a list in the plain text version.

Answer (score 1):

No. Display of plain-text email is entirely up to the client. You have no control over it. If you want control, use HTML.

Comment: I'm already using HTML, but including plain text as a fallback if ever required by some strangely outdated customer's email system **(or for a customer who set even the latest client to show plain text version by preference)**. My goal is to have plain text as close as possible to the HTML version.

Comment: Sure, but no amount of wishing will give you rendering control over plain-text messages. That's what makes them plain-text messages; if they allowed formatting, they wouldn't be plain text.

Comment: Well yes I understand and I'm aware there is no such thing as formatting in plain text. But I wanted to know if there is some way to tell the email client to use a `monospace` font to display it. Perhaps by way of a hint in the email header (if such a universally recognized hint exists). [But I'm guessing nothing of that sort exists.]